# Execute Docker Run and check parameter is not empty

Tags: docker, dockerfile

How do I check if the parameter ENV  was passed while executing the docker run.

I want to display an error message if the paramenter is not passed.

Thanks

Comment: You can echo the variable, and, if the output is blank, then one can assume the variable was not set. Is this helpful?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could do this, inside your StartUP Script for the Service.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$VARIABLE" ]; then
  echo "The VARIABLE is not set"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thank's for your help! Is there anyway when I run docker run with param -d show some message? This code works fine but only if a run without param -d show de message.

Comment: Detached is detached, so i would guess: no , you could mount a local volume and write a textfile or run "docker logs containerID"

Answer (score -1):

if its to inspect env on running container you can use `docker inspect --format '{{ index (index .Config.Env) 0 }}' $CONTAINER_ID`
 the 0 number is represent the number of how many env the container is using.. in this case it would print the first env . .